# Entity Relationship Diagram - Where are the purchases?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Considering that this community has questions related to modeling databases, I am here seeking help.

I'm developing an auction system based on another one seen in a book I'm reading, and I'm having trouble. The problem context is the following:

> In the auction system, a user makes product announcements (he/she defines a product). It defines
>   the product name, and the initial offer (called initial bid). The initial bid expresses the minimum amount to be offering. A
>   product only exists in the database when it is announced by a user. A
>   user defines a number of products, but a product belongs to a single
>   user.
>
> Every product has an expiration date. When a certain date arrives, if
>   there are no offers for the product, it is not sold. If there are
>   offers for the product, the highest bidder wins the given product.
>
> The offers have a creation date, and the amount offered. An offer is
>   made to a product from a user. A user can make different offers for
>   different products. A product can be offered by different users. The
>   same user can not do more than two offers for the same product.

This kind of context for me is easy to do. **The problem is that I need to store a purchase.** (I'm sorry, but I do not know if the word is that in English). I need a way to know which offer was successful, and actually "bought" a product. Relative to what was said, part of my Conceptual Model (Entity Relationship Diagram) is as follows:

[image: so far...]

I've tried to aggregate USERS with PRODUCTS, and make a connection/relationship between the aggregation and PRODUCTS, which would give me the PURCHASES event. When this was broken down (decomposed) I would have a table showing which offer bought what product.

Nevertheless, I would have a cardinality problem. This table would have two foreign keys. One for BIDS, and the other for PRODUCTS. This would allow an N-N relationship of these two, meaning that I could save more than one bid as the buyer of a product, or that the same bid could "buy" many products (so I say in the resulting PURCHASES table).

Am I not seeing something here? Can you guys help me with this? Thank you for reading, for your time, and patience. And if you need some more detail, please do not hesitate to ask.

### EDIT

The property "Initial Bid" on the PRODUCTS entity is not a relationship.
This property represents a monetary value, a minimum amount that an offer must have to be given to a particular product.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching things backwards. First we determine a relevant application relationship, then we determine its properties. Given an application relationship and the possible application situations that can arise, only certain relationship/association sets/tables can arise. A purchase can have only one bid per product and one product per bid. So it is just a fact that the bid:product cardinality of PURCHASES is 1:1. Say so. This is so regardless of what other application relationships you wish to record. If it were a different application relationship between those entities then the cardinality might be different. Wait--USERS_PRODUCTS and BIDS form exactly such a pair of appplication relationships, with user:product being 1:0..N for the former and 0..N:0..N for the latter. Cardinality for each participant reflects (is a property of) *the particular application relationship that a diamond represents*.

Similarly: Foreign keys are properties of pairs of relationship/association sets/tables. Declaring them tells the DBMS to enforce that participant id values appear in entity sets/tables. Ie {bid} referencing BIDS and {product} referencing PRODUCTS. And candidate keys (of which one can be a primary key) are a property of a relationship set/table. It is the candidate keys of PURCHASES that lead to declaration of a constraint that enforces its cardinality. It isn't many:many on bid:product because "bid BID purchased product PRODUCT at price $AMOUNT on date DATE" isn't many:many on bid:product. Since either its bid or its product uniquely identify a purchase both {bid} and {product} are candidate keys.

Answer (score 0):

To record the winning bid requires a functional dependency `Product ID -> Bid ID`.  This could be implemented as one or more nullable columns (since not all products have been purchased yet) in the `Products` table, or better in a separate table (Purchases) using `Product ID` as primary key.

Comment: Hi @reaanb, thank you for your time. You said: "...the same way as Initial Bid...", did you say to create a nullable column in PRODUCTS? And your other suggestion... I do not quite understand what you meant. Could you please ellaborate your answer?

Comment: I hope the revised answer helps.  I can be more specific after you decide on a primary key for bids.

Comment: I guess I was not clear about the Initial Bid column. This does not represent a relationship between entities, but a monetary value. This value represents the minimum amount that an offer should have for a given product. "as one or more nullable columns in the Products table", this does not seem right. Generally null columns may be replaced by relationships in the conceptual model. "or better in a separate table (Purchases) using the Product ID as primary key." How would that be, and what relationships I would have with this entity?

Comment: @Loa We know that Products initial_bid is an attribute/propery. The proposal for a Purchases relationship is to have the FKs in Purchases be to Product id_product & to the key of *Bids*. The equivalent alternate proposal is to not have that explicit relationship but instead add the would-be fields of Purchases to Product as nullable since in Purchases purchaces:bids (that's purchase:bid (that's purchase bids not product initial bids) is 1:0..1.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding of the initial bid column.  My recommendation was to establish an optional 1-to-1 relationship between products and bids to record the winning bid per product.

Comment: I revised my answer to eliminate the initial bid confusion and reflect your choice of primary key for bids.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I tried to follow the given advices, and also tried to follow what I had previously spoken to do, using aggregation. It seems to me that the result is correct. Please observe:

[image]

Of course, a user makes offers for products. A user record can relate to multiple records in PRODUCTS. Likewise, a product can be offered by multiple users, and thus, a record in PRODUCTS can relate to multiple records on USERS. If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.

Looking at purchase, we see that a product is only properly purchased by a single bid. There is no way to say that a user buys a product, or a product purchase itself. It is through the relationship between USERS and PRODUCTS that an bid is created, and it is an bid that is able to buy a product. Thus, it is necessary to aggregate such a relationship, then set the purchase event.

We must remember that only one product can be purchased for a single bid. So here we have a cardinality of 1 to 1. Decomposition here will ask discretion of the data modeler.

By decomposing this Conceptual Model, we will have the following Logic Model:

[image]

Notice how relationships are respected with appropriate attributes. We can know who announced a product (the seller), and we can know what offers were made to it.

Now, as I said before, there is the PURCHASES relationship. As we have a relationship of 1 to 1 here, the rule tells us that we must choose which side the relationship will be interpreted (which entity shall keep such a relationship).

It is usually recommended to keep the relationship on the side that is likely in the future to become a "many". There is no need to do so in this case because it is clear that this relationship can not be preserved in a BIDS record. Therefore, we maintain such a relationship portrayed by "Winner Bid" on the PRODUCTS entity. As you can see, I set a unique identifier for BIDS. By defining the Physical Model, we have a surrogate key.

---

Well, I finish my answer here, but I think I can not consider it right yet. I would like someone to comment anything if possible. Thank you.

### EDIT

I'd like to apologize. It seems that there was a mistake on my part. Well, I currently live in Brazil, and here we learn the ER-Diagram in a way that seems to me to be different from what many of you are used to. Until yesterday I've been answering some questions related to the subject here in the community, and I found odd certain different notations used. Only now I'm noticing that we are not speaking the same language. I believe it was embarrassing for me in a way. I'm sorry. Really, I'm sorry.

Oh, and one more thing (it may be interesting for someone):

- The cardinality between BIDS and PRODUCTS is really wrong. It should
  be 0 to 1 in both, as was said in the comments.
- There are no relationships relating with relationships here. We have
  what is called here (in my country, or in my past course)
  "Aggregation" (Represented in the first drawing by the rectangle with clipped lines). The internal relationship (BIDS) when decomposed will
  become an entity, and the relationship between BIDS and PRODUCTS is
  made later. An aggregation says that a relationship needs to be resolved first so that it can relate with another entity. This creates a certain restriction, which may be necessary in certain business rules. It says that the joining of two entities define records that relate to records of another entity.
- Certain relationships do not necessarily need to be named. Once you
  break down certain types of relationships, there is no need (it's
  optional) to name them (between relations N to N), especially if new
  relationship does not arise from these. Of course, if I were to name the white relationships presented, we then would have USER'S BIDS (between USERS and BIDS), and PRODUCT'S BIDS (between BIDS and PRODUCTS).

With respect to my study material, it's all in portuguese, and I believe you will not understand, I do not know. But here's one of the books I read during my past classes:

- ISBN: 978-85-365-0252-6
- Title: PROJETO de BANCO de DADOS Uma Visão Prática
- Authors: Felipe Machado, Mauricio Abreu
- Publishing company: EDITORA ÉRICA
- COVER:

[image]

- LINK:
  http://www.editorasaraiva.com.br/produtos/show/isbn:9788536502526/titulo:projeto-de-banco-de-dados-uma-visao-pratica-edicao-revisada-e-atualizada/

Well... What do I do now? Haha... I do not know what to do. I'll leave my question here. If someone with the same method that I can help me, I'll be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to just need an *associative entity* (box+diamond allowing a realtionship to participate in a relationship), not an *aggregate entity* (dashed-boundary allowing an entire part of the diagram to be one entity). The aggregate seems wrong: USERS_PRODUCTS (ANNOUNCEMENTS) is a relationship between BIDS & BIDS in two roles but since not all users are involved in bidding  there may be no bid available to be the announcer of a product.

Comment: Please delete this as an answer and post it as a question since it is so different from your original question.

Comment: Please look for references and/or a bibliography at the end of your textbook or its ERD chapter(s) in case they mention an English-language source or sources for their ERDs.

Comment: @Loa It looks like you implemented the functional dependency `Product ID -> Winning Bid ID` as a nullable column in the Products table, as I originally suggested.  The model looks usable.  However, I have a few more comments on the content of your post:

Comment: `Of course, a user makes offers for products. A user record can relate to multiple records in PRODUCTS. Likewise, a product can be offered by multiple users, and thus, a record in PRODUCTS can relate to multiple records on USERS. If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.`  This paragraph appears to mix up bids and products for sale.  A product can be bid on by multiple users, but `a product belongs to a single user` as in your original problem context.

Comment: `As we have a relationship of 1 to 1 here, the rule tells us that we must choose which side the relationship will be interpreted (which entity shall keep such a relationship).`  In Chen's original ER model, relationships were implemented as separate tables, not recorded in entity tables.  You may find it worthwhile to read http://www.inf.unibz.it/~nutt/IDBs1011/IDBPapers/chen-ER-TODS-76.pdf.

Comment: `it is clear that this relationship can not be preserved in a BIDS record.`  A simple yes/no indicator in the Bids relation could indicate whether a bid won or not, but that would lead to poor integrity and difficult queries.

Comment: I can adjust to your diagram notation with one comments: I would not use a diamond-box (associative entity) on a relation that has a surrogate id, only on those using composite foreign keys as primary key and which are involved in other relationships.  Again, see Chen's paper.  `By defining the Physical Model, we have a surrogate key.` Please don't believe that every table must use a surrogate ID.

Comment: `The cardinality between BIDS and PRODUCTS is really wrong. It should be 0 to 1 in both, as was said in the comments.`  It looks correct me - a product can be bid on many times.